# How to get a list of databases?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if there's a way in **PHP** to list all **available databases** by usage of **mysqli**. The following works smooth in **MySQL** (see [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php)):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {
 echo $row->Database . "\n";
}
```

Can I Change:

```
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link); // mysql
```

Into something like:

```
$db_list = mysqli_list_dbs($link); // mysqli
```

If this is not working, would it be possible to convert a created **mysqli** connection into a regular **mysql** and continue fetching/querying on the new converted connection?

Comment: Apologies. Using mysqli you can run "show databases" instead.

Comment: If anyone is thinking of using `mysql_list_dbs`, it will stop working in the future as it is **deprecated**. More info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php . So better to use the code from one of the answers, below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't appear as though there's a function available to do this, but you can execute a `show databases;` query and the rows returned will be the databases available.

EXAMPLE:

Replace this:

```
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link); //mysql
```

With this:

```
$db_list = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW DATABASES"); //mysqli
```

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old thread but, searching the 'net still doesn't seem to help. Here's my solution;

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES";
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql: ' . mysqli_error($link).'\r\n');

if (!($result=mysqli_query($link,$sql))) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ) ){
        if (($row[0]!="information_schema") && ($row[0]!="mysql")) {
            echo $row[0]."\r\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DenizZoeteman It wasn't necessary for you to comment on a post that directly answers the question regardless of the age. It helped me and that completely negates your point. Yeah, the same info is elsewhere on the internet, but it's not always presented the right way for everyone to understand. Some people and their high horses...

Comment: I have this code to get database list but it is returning only one schema "information_schema", why not all databases? Please help

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Rick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452867/1617737), but this is the way to do it if you prefer to use **mysqli** in object-orientated fashion:

```
$mysqli = ... // This object is my equivalent of Rick's $link object.

$sql = "SHOW DATABASES";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
    throw new Exception("Could not execute query: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$db_names = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) { // for each row of the resultset
    $db_names[] = $row[0]; // Add db name to $db_names array
}

echo "Database names: " . PHP_EOL . print_r($db_names, TRUE); // display array
```

Comment: Relevant: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete and extended solution for the answer, there are some databases that you do not need to read because those databases are system databases and we do not want them to appear on our result set, these system databases differ by the setup you have in your SQL so this solution will help in any kind of situations.

first you have to make database connection in OOP

```
//error reporting Procedural way
//mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

//error reporting OOP way
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","kasun12345");
```

using Index array of search result

```
$dbtoSkip = array("information_schema","mysql","performance_schema","sys");

$result = $conn->query("show databases");
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    $print = true;

    foreach($dbtoSkip as $key=>$vlue){
        if($row[0] == $vlue) {
            $print=false;
            unset($dbtoSkip[$key]);
        }
    }

    if($print){
        echo '<br/>'.$row[0];
    }
}
```

same with Assoc array of search result

```
$dbtoSkip = array("information_schema","mysql","performance_schema","sys"); 

$result = $conn->query("show databases");
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $print = true;

    foreach($dbtoSkip as $key=>$vlue){
        if($row["Database"] == $vlue) {
            $print=false;
            unset($dbtoSkip[$key]);
        }
    }

    if($print){
        echo '<br/>'.$row["Database"]; 
    }
}
```

same using object of search result

```
$dbtoSkip = array("information_schema","mysql","performance_schema","sys"); 

$result = $conn->query("show databases");
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
    $print = true;
    foreach($dbtoSkip as $key=>$vlue){
        if( $obj->Database == $vlue) {
            $print=false;
            unset($dbtoSkip[$key]);
        }
    }

    if($print){
        echo '<br/>'. $obj->Database;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tried several examples from above, but couldn't get it to work, errors like array to string conversion etc...
So I made this function and it works perfectly for me (the function `connect()` on line 3 connects to information_schema.
The preg_match at the bottom filters out the standard databases (I am not so familiar with preg_match, maybe I could have done it in another way better).

```
function showDatabases () {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = connect();
    $resultarray = array(); 
    $dbquery = "SELECT * FROM `SCHEMATA`";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $dbquery);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    foreach($result as $datakey => $datavalue) {
        array_push($resultarray, $datavalue);
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    $arraycount = count($resultarray);
    echo "Number of entries: $arraycount<br><br>";
    
    for ($x=0;$x<$arraycount;$x++) {
        if(!preg_match('/schema/', $resultarray[$x]['SCHEMA_NAME']) AND !preg_match('/myadmin/', $resultarray[$x]['SCHEMA_NAME'])) {
            print_r($resultarray[$x]['SCHEMA_NAME']);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    close();
}
```

Comment: This is hugely overcomplicated. You don't need any preg_match nor most of the functions used here.

Comment: All you need is just a single database query. [Here is how it should be](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/435c95703d95e6ec214a667e5cd75aad/)

Comment: @Your Common Sense thnx, this dóes work but also throws a warning first, which I can't get rid of: Warning: Undefined variable $mysqli ... but yes, I dó agree, this is simpler

Comment: Oh COME ON. When working with a database you need to connect first. So you need a variable that holds a connection. This is called mysqli in my example but in your case it could be $db, $conn or whatever.