# I want to correspond a database,php told me that unknown database but when I use cmd it is worked

Tags: php, mysql

The specific situation is that when I try to use the database named"maskorder", I find that I can't connect to the database. I can guarantee that I have completed the establishment of the database and named it maskorder, and there is no problem using the database through CMD. However, when when I need to use the database, the error message displays "unknown database 'maskorder'", After repeatedly consulting the data and trying, I found that this error occurs in all databases except the test database, and no similar situation is found in the Q & A that can be found. My codes as belows:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","maskorder");
$link or die('error：'.mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($link, "maskorder")
or die('error：'.mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_query($link, "set names utf8");
```

and the next is my MySql database:

[image]

then is screenshot of CMD

[image]

Comment: Not related to the problem, but if you supply a database in `mysqli_connect()` you don't need to call `mysqli_select_db()`

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database server as when you test with the command line?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure

Comment: Can you also post the screenshot of the CMD that works? Curious to see the output.

Comment: I have added the screenshot, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Did you tried change db host from **127.0.0.1** to **localhost** in `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: Yes, even I have tried change the port, but both are useless

Comment: @liushanshan When you connect to the MySQL server without specifying the database and send a `SHOW DATABASES` query, what result do you get? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677279/how-to-get-a-list-of-databases)

Comment: @Progman Thank you, I find where was wrong)
I used Appserv, and it has its own MySql. When I tried to connect with the database, It used another MySql which is not the one has been used in cmd